# All open questions on a Stack Exchange site

Tags: support, search

If a Stack Exchange site has, say, 25k questions, then not all of them are necessarily "open" questions, i.e., many are put on hold as well (duplicate, offtopic, etc.).

I wish to know if there's a method to know the total count (and if possible, view all) of the *open* questions on a Stack Exchange site.

Comment: search with [`closed:0`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3A0)

Comment: @rene That works! Thanks

Comment: @rene Does it count only questions or also the answers separately?

Comment: closed only works for questions. Answers can't be closed. See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching